# exists query does not return relevant result

Tags: sql, laravel, eloquent

I have a Laravel application with this Eloquent query:

```
$products = Product::where('name', 'LIKE', "%{$value}%")
    ->whereHas('categories', function($q) {
        $q->where( 'slug', 'tonery-cartridge' );
    })->with('manufacturer')
    ->with('sm_image')
    ->orderBy('created_at','DESC')
    ->take(10)
    ->get();
```

This code generates the sql command like:

```
select * from `products` where `name` LIKE '%can%' 
    and exists (
        select * from `categories` inner join `category_product` 
            on `categories`.`id` = `category_product`.`category_id` 
            where `products`.`id` = `category_product`.`product_id` 
            and `slug` = 'tonery-cartridge'
    )
order by `created_at` desc limit 10
```

I am sure there are products which name contains "can" string and which belongs to the category with slug "tonery-cartridge". Why this query returns an empty result? If I try to make `inner join` sql manually it works well as on the screenshot below:

[image: phpMyAdmin screenshot]

Comment: Try `$q->where( 'categories.slug', 'tonery-cartridge' );` Are the manufacturer and sm_image relations on Product ,odel?

Comment: it is the same. And yes sm_image and manufacturer are the relations on the product model.

Comment: Maybe you defined the relationship `categories()` wrong in your Product model.

Comment: I dont think so:


    public function categories()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(\App\Category::class);
    }

Comment: Try `Product::where('name', 'ilike', "%{$value}%")` because as seen from the image the name column in products table contains Canon as well as CANON so the comparison needs to be case insensitive for the query to work

Comment: No the collation is utf8_slovak_ci which means it is case insensitive.

Comment: Can you pleae explain what you mean with ```If I try to make inner join sql manually it works```? What do you mean with ```manually```? Do you mean with that that you write the SQL code yourself instead the one that is returned by Laravel?

Comment: Yes I mean I wrote it as a raw sql to the phpmyadmin.

Comment: Thank you for making that clear! I think that the SQL query you wrote and the one returned by laravel are not equivalent.

Comment: So what is the difference?

Comment: One is the you are doing an innerjoin of tables on which you perform your query, while the laravel one das not. Which may be the cause of it. I have posted an answer, maybe this will guide you to the correct answer. Unfortunatley, I can not try it out since I do not have the data base.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that your queries are not equivalent. The `SQL` output from laravel does not join tables in it's `FROM` clause, but in your manually constructed `SQL` statement you do a lot of inner joins in your `FROM` clause and on the **resulting** table you perform your operations, which is not true for the former.

Try the following

```php
DB::table('products')
    ->join('category_product', 'category_product.product_id', '=', 'products.id')
    ->join('categories', 'category_product.category_id', '=', 'categories.id')
    ->whereRaw('products.name LIKE %can% AND categories.slug = "tonery-cartridge"')
    ->select('products.name', 'categories.slug')
    ->orderBy('created_at','DESC')
    ->take(10)
    ->get()
```

If you want to avoid using `whereRaw`, you can try the following.

```php
DB::table('products')
    ->join('category_product', 'category_product.product_id', '=', 'products.id')
    ->join('categories', 'category_product.category_id', '=', 'categories.id')
    ->where([
              ['products.name, 'LIKE', '%' .  $value . '%'],
              ['categories.slug', '=', 'tonery-cartridge']])
    ->select('products.name', 'categories.slug')
    ->orderBy('created_at','DESC')
    ->take(10)
    ->get()
```

HTH

Comment: Thansk. There is also another way but this works. One question. If I run this join query to get products ids and then call Product::whereIn('id', $ids) to get necessary relations is it ok or is it overkill to do it this way?

Comment: @Čamo The ```IN``` keyword in ```SQL``` is a selector. For example, if you have ```WHERE Country IN ('USA', 'UK', 'Japan')```, then the output will contain only rows where where the value of ```column Country``` is either ```USA```, ```ÙK```, or ```Japan```. In your specific case I would say it is simply not necessary because you do not need to select for certain ```id```'s, do you?

Comment: But this is only query for condition category.slug and product.name and I need much more relations for the product, like translations, images, status, brand ... so the query would be too complicated to get all this stuff in one. Thats the reason why I am asking about ids and whereIn() in next separate sql.

Comment: I think we are not talking about the same thing. You seem to talk about selecting columns, where the ```IN``` statement operates on the values in columns. For example, you want to include the column ```brand``` in your output. Correct?

Comment: No I want to get regular Eloquent entities as a result of the two operations. First one gets a joined table which returns products ids and the second one which will create collection with Eloquent entities according whereIn('id', $ids).

Comment: I think I know what you mean. You want to create a query that returns a column ```id```. Then this column is supposed to be the range of ```id``` `s you wish to select for in the second query. It this correct? If yes, then this can be easily done (in fact you just described how it is done). Anyhow, you might consider opening another question for this issue since it is not in the problem context of the OP.

Comment: :D I want to know your opinion if this use case is ok. I know how it works but I dont know if it is right way to do it.

Comment: Yes, this use case is ok. :)

Comment: Thanks a lot. Have a nice day.

Answer (score 1):

This could be one of the solutions

```
$category = Category::where( 'slug', 'tonery-cartridge' )->first();


$products = $category->products()
   ->where('name', 'LIKE', "%{$value}%")
   ->with('manufacturer')
   ->with('sm_image')
   ->latest()
   ->take(10)
   ->get();
```